# How to use Jasmine JS to intercept simple jQuery functions?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I have this in production code:

```
$(document).ready ->      
  if $( "#accordion" ).length > 0
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion()
```

Which works, and I would like to test it:

```
describe "Non-MVCd stuff", ->
  beforeEach ->
    spyOn( $('#accordion').prototype, 'accordion' )
    if $("#accordion").length > 0 
      $("#accordion").accordion()

  describe "accordion", ->
    it 'works', ->
      expect( $('#accordion' ).length ).toBe( 1, 'the element must be there.' )
      expect( $('#accordion').prototype.accordion ).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

I get this error:

```
spyOn could not find an object to spy upon for accordion()
TypeError: $(...).prototype is undefined in http://pi.local:3011/assets/spec/views/utils_spec.js?body=1 (line 14)
```

Without the prototype it also does not work ( and, $("#accordion").prototype is undefined ):

```
describe "Non-MVCd stuff", ->
  beforeEach ->
    spyOn( $('#accordion'), 'accordion' )
    if $("#accordion").length > 0 
      $("#accordion").accordion()
  describe "accordion", ->
    it 'works', ->
      expect( $('#accordion' ).length ).toBe( 1, 'the element must be there.' )
      expect( $('#accordion').accordion ).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

_

```
Error: Expected a spy, but got Function. in http://pi.local:3011/assets/jasmine-1.1.0/jasmine.js?body=1 (line 1286)
```

Comment: Have you tried attaching your spying to `$.fn.accordion`? `$(x).prototype` is `undefined` for me...

Comment: Mu, great that works. Now can you explain, how to put the spyOn() function before my call to $('#accordion').accordion() ? I can call it again in my specs, but I would like not to. I would like the spyOn() call to be before before I include all my production js.

Comment: I don't know Jasmine that well but couldn't you `spyOn($.fn, 'accordion')` at the top of `beforeEach` or something like that? Either that or maybe you could `@accordion = $("#accordion")` in `beforeEach` and spy on `@accordion`. Each time you do `$('#accordion')`, you're creating a new jQuery object that wraps `#accordion` so any spies you have will get lost.

Comment: Mu, that's what I was doing but it doesn't work. Right now I don't see a way in my current js architecture to do the spyOn() before my production logic is loaded. However, your first answer satisfies my question so if you wanna re-write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome to provide your own answer, I've just been throwing around guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following code to spy on object function like this.

```
spyOn($.fn, 'accordion' )
```

Or for normal method.

```
spyOn([ObjectName].prototype, '[methodName]' )
```